# How do i display the selected value in multiselect while editing and updating the options(codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

How do i display the selected value in multiselect while editing and updating the options.

my multiselect function is:

```
foreach ($subjects as $sub){

 $subject_selected[]=$sub['subject_name'];

}

echo  form_multiselect('subject[]',$subject_list,'',$js,$subject_selected); ?>
```

if I m wrong please correct me..

Answer (score 3):

It should be like

```
echo form_multiselect('subject[]',$subject_list,$subject_selected,$js); ?>
```

> Lets you create a standard multiselect field. The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third parameter will contain the value or values you wish to be selected. The parameter usage is identical to using form_dropdown() above, except of course that the name of the field will need to use POST array syntax, e.g. foo[].

Comment: Its not working..
print_r($subject_selected) gives
array([0]=>accounts[1]=>history)

i want this two subjects to remain selected in the multiselect options..

Comment: then I think you need to use array_values($subject_selected) if your options "values" are like accounts,history

Comment: Then i didnt knw where the mistake...upto my extent and content which I got this is correct...check your code and check whether the option values and your $subject_selected values

Comment: `$subject_selected`'s values need to match the **keys** in the `$subject_list` array. Given your print_r, your `$subject_list` array should look something like `array('accounts' => 'Accounts', 'history' => 'History')`...

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for this thing and have failed so many times. But at last find a way around to resolve the issue.

This is the way that I have came across with.

```
<?php
                $manpower_list = array();
                $manpowers = $this->db->select('m.id, m.manpower_name')
                                ->from('task_manpower tm')
                                ->join('manpower m', 'tm.manpower_id = m.id')
                                ->where('tm.deleted', 0)->where('m.deleted', 0)
                                ->where('tm.task_id', $model_info->id)
                                ->get()->result();
                foreach ($manpowers as $power) {
                    $manpower_list[] = $power->id;
                }
            ?>
        <?php echo form_dropdown("manpower_id[]", $manpower_dropdown, $manpower_list, "class='select2 validate-hidden form-control' id='manpower_id' multiple='multiple'"); ?>
```

Hope it helps someone.